# Como hacer que se imprima el array con elementos que coincidan

Tags: array, c

```c
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h>

int main()  
{ 
     srand(time(0));
     char hebra_original[5] = {'A', 'G', 'T', 'C'}; 
     char hebra_transcripta[5] = {'A', 'G', 'T', 'C'};   
     printf("Hebra molde de ADN: ");
     for(int i = 0; i < 80; ++i)
     {
         printf("%c", hebra_original[rand() % 4]);
     } 
     return 0; 
}
```

Mi pregunta es, cómo puedo hacer que el array "hebra_transcripta" (A, G, T, C); se imprima acorde a la hebra random(hebra_molde)?

Me explico; al correr el programa se imprimen 80 letras aleatorias dentro del arreglo
(A, G, T, C), cómo puedo hacer que el array "hebra_transcripta", si hay una T en hebra_original, que imprima una A; si hay una G en hebra_original, que imprima una C; y así sucesivamente.

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar un ejemplo donde se refleje de forma clara el resultado que esperas?

Comment: Hola, disculpa no haberla subido antes; (https://ibb.co/Hng2NKR) ahi esta el resultado. @MrDave1999

Comment: Trata de agregar el resultado directamente en la pregunta, no en los comentarios..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No necesitamos dos *arrays* para que guarde `AGTC`, con uno basta:

```c
char hebra[] = {"AGTC"};
```

Lo que si necesitamos esta vez, es un *array* de 80 elementos donde guarde los valores aleatorios. De esto depende poder imprimir la `hebra_transcripta`.

El código quedaría así:

```c
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h>

#define N 80

int main()  
{ 
    srand(time(0));
    char hebra[] = {"AGTC"};
    char hebra_random[N];
    printf("Hebra molde de ADN: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        hebra_random[i] = hebra[rand() % 4];
        putchar(hebra_random[i]);
    } 
    printf("\nHebra comp ADN:     ");
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        switch(hebra_random[i])
        {
            case 'A':
                putchar('T');
                break;
            case 'G':
                putchar('C');
                break;
            case 'T':
                putchar('A');
                break;
            case 'C':
                putchar('G');
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Cada caracter aleatorio lo almacenamos en el *array* `hebra_random`, ya que luego lo usaremos en el segundo bucle para imprimir el caracter contrario (esto lo hacemos a través del `switch`).

Answer (score 1):

Es tan sencillo como tener formaciones<sup>1</sup> de transcripción.

No soy experto, pero una búsqueda me indica que:

- Tiamina se empareja con Adenina (T-A).
- Guanina se empareja con Citosina (G-C).

Así que teniendo el enumerado:

```
enum Base
{
    A, C, G, T
};
```

Podemos construir estas formaciones:

```
enum Base original[] = { A, C, G, T };
enum Base pareja[]   = { T, G, C, A };
char letra[]    = { 'A', 'C', 'G', 'T' };
```

Por lo tanto, para transcribir una hebra, basta con leer la base original y buscar en la formación de base transcrita:

```
enum Base cadena[5] = { original[rand() % 4], original[rand() % 4], original[rand() % 4], original[rand() % 4] };

printf("Hebra original: ");
for (int i = 0; i != 5; ++i)
    printf("%c", letra[cadena[i]]);

printf("\nHebra transcrita: ");
for (int i = 0; i != 5; ++i)
    printf("%c", letra[pareja[cadena[i]]]);
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZC/TsMwEIfn@CmOoCqJahADXQhFCh3KA2QrGa622x5KneqSsFR99uD8UVLUDZazdPf5fp@tHlSOdt8092RVXmsDr2WlqXg8vIlfrZy2bU8YWx/hHUsDZ0gkrCSsJaRwia9HBdOeLOabDJY33ISdkM0XOgg6LO0YRyYtpg7IkJuKe6AjgiSQEKzasm5LGnTBZCs4ItnwuyAdibPwpgyF2ljcLHqTUYzR6jCCGTxn8t/dTsI7sfPYhf6H2TKO3Av4USy8XcEQtp7kPJ5id9wtYRHDfE6R8Ma7M@XL4dGDOGVZdL390/b7HWJLxVThnxOG75@C@iQ2Vc3WrRCXpvkB)</kbd>.

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocidas como *arreglos* o en inglés *arrays*.